# Running resque without Rakefile

Tags: ruby, resque

I have built my own job server, which is essentially a private gem, built as a wrapper around [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque).

(I am not running this in a Rails environment)

Everywhere I look, it seems like the documented/recommended way to start the workers, is with something like this:

```
$ QUEUE=* rake resque:work
```

Which means that it must be executed in a folder where the Rakefile exists.

I am looking for a way to start it without a Rakefile.

What I have learned so far:

- I have looked through the [issues](https://github.com/resque/resque/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20without%20without%20rakefile), maybe someone asked a similar question.
- I have looked through the [wiki](https://github.com/resque/resque/wiki), and specifically the [FAQ](https://github.com/resque/resque/wiki/FAQ).
- I know I can probably create my own "bin" to run it without rake, by analyzing the [tasks file](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/lib/resque/tasks.rb).
- I saw that resque installs a `resque` binary, but it only seems to provide limited functionality, like removing and listing a worker, but not starting.
- My current workaround is that my gem's binary is doing `chdir` to the gem's folder before running (and this folder has a Rakefile), like the code below.

---

```
def start_worker
  ENV['QUEUE'] = '*'
  Dir.chdir gemdir do
    exec "rake resque:work"
  end
end

def gemdir
  File.expand_path "../../", __dir__
end
```

Appreciate any nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The current solution I have worked up for this:

```
def start_worker
  interval = 5
  queue = '*'

  ENV['QUEUE'] = queue
  worker = Resque::Worker.new
  Resque.logger = Logger.new STDOUT
  Resque.logger.level = Logger::INFO

  ## this is not yet implemented in 1.26.0, keeping here as a reminder
  # worker.prepare  

  worker.log "Starting worker"
  worker.work interval
end
```

Which is an adaptation of the [code from the rake task](https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/lib/resque/tasks.rb#L9)

For reference, I also opened a [github issue](https://github.com/resque/resque/issues/1504), in the off chance that someone else also needs such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I having created a script to create demon worker processes using following worker starting API.

```
def start_worker(id)
  ENV['QUEUE'] = @queues || "*"
  ENV['PIDFILE'] = pid_file(id)
  ENV['JOBS_PER_FORK'] = @jobs_per_fork || "1000"
  ENV['BACKGROUND'] = 'true'
  ENV['TERM_CHILD'] = 'true'
  @debug ? ENV['VVERBOSE'] = 'true' : ENV['VERBOSE'] = 'true'

  begin
    worker = Resque::Worker.new
  rescue Resque::NoQueueError
    Resque.logger.error "No queue is set for worker_id = #{id}"
  end

  worker.prepare
  worker.log "Starting worker #{self}"
  worker.work(5) # interval, will block
end
```